# How to run a simple python script on heroku without flask/django?

Tags: python, heroku

I'm trying to run a simple hello world python program on my heroku server. I'm new to heroku.I was able to successfully deploy my script to heroku.
My python script and procfile are given below,

hi.py

```
print("hello world")
```

Procfile

```
web: python hi.py
```

I got "Hello world" as output when i ran `heroku run web` on my terminal.But when i try to run the app using heroku web url it shows the following error.

> Application Error An error occurred in the application and your page
>   could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

What did i do wrong here? I'm newbie to heroku & its concepts, please do bare.

Comment: look at your logfiles to see what the error is ... but basically thats not how it works ... the web interface calls a method and expects an httpresponse object  ..   why not just use flask?

Comment: Error log shows following , Starting process with command `python hi.py`
app[web.1]: hello
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=jar1.herokuapp.com request_id=f86bf99b-862c-428a-a123-dcfdc1cb29dd fwd="117.245.47.245" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-02-16T17:37:20.610858+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"

Comment: I think that means that stdout was printed to and the application exited without returning ... and so it "crashed" with exit code 0

Comment: I dont know flask or Django. I just want to sequentially execute a simple python script when i run the app using web URL. is it possible ?

Comment: even in that case it should print "hello world" to the browser right?

Comment: wrong ... since it clearly does not ... (even though you can see it in your logs that it "printed")

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I disagree and state you want flask

**main_app.py**

```
import flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    #do whatevr here...
    return "Hello Heruko"
```

then change your procfile to `web: gunicorn main_app:app --log-file -`

Comment: Hello @JoranBeasley, I use Google Apps Script to do some tasks and I would like to call a Python code that I deployed to Heroku from GAS. The way you indicated I managed to do this, the problem is that the web is active all the time and consumes all my account dyno hors and I only call the code three times a day. Is there any way to do this without using web leaving the code disabled until I actually call it? I created a question with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73172151/using-google-apps-script-to-call-heroku-for-run-python-code-deployed-on-the-plat

Answer (score 18):

There are [three types of dyno configurations](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos) available on Heroku:

- Web -- receives web traffic.
- Worker -- keeps processing tasks/queues in the background.
- One-off -- executed once. e.g.: backup.

If you're interested in running a script, do not care about receiving web traffic on it, and don't have a queue to process, then **[One-off dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos)** are likely what you'll want to use. This would be useful for database migrations or backups and whatnot.

Minimal example below.

---

#### Sample one-off dyno with Heroku and python AKA “hello world”

This assumes you have already created your app on Heroku and are able to use Herolu CLI from the command-line.

A minimal “hello world” Python script would then look like this. Only 2 files required:

- `requirements.txt` Required, but can be left empty.
- `task.py` with content `print("hello world")`

Then deploy to Heroku, e.g.:

```
git add .;
git commit -m "My first commit";
git push heroku master
```

After that, you'll be able to run your script with `heroku run python task.py` (and should see the long-awaited `hello world` in the output.)

If you want to run your program at specific times, use the free Heroku Scheduler add-on.

FYI, `Procfile` is optional. If you set it to `hello: python task.py` then you'll be able to run your program with just `heroku run hello`.

*(Note that leaving `requirements.txt` empty will trigger `You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")` warnings on deploy. It's just a warning though and doesn't prevent proper deployment of the program.)*