# Deploying a simple python script to Heroku without Flask or Django

Tags: python, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a python script, but I get this error

```
Failed to detect app matching https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz buildpack
```

What files I have right now:

**automation.py**

A simple python script which imports  **praw**, **time**, **os** and **inspect**.

**requirements.txt**

As described in the Heroku documents, I have created this file by running `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, containing:

```
astroid==1.5.2
colorama==0.3.8
isort==4.2.5
lazy-object-proxy==1.2.2
mccabe==0.6.1
praw==4.4.1.dev0
prawcore==0.10.1
pylint==1.7.1
requests==2.13.0
six==1.10.0
update-checker==0.16
wrapt==1.10.10
```

**runtime.txt**

Again as described in Heroku documents, this file contains the runtime for my script, containing:

```
python-3.6.0
```

I have changed my remote to heroku, added all files, commited and pushed to heroku master, but I get the error mentioned in the beginning. Is there something I'm doing wrong? I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438949/how-to-run-a-simple-python-script-on-heroku-without-flask-django), but I'm not convinced. Would like to avoid any frameworks if possible.

**git ls-files output**

```
.gitignore
LICENSE
README.md
requirements.txt
runtime.txt
automation.py
```

Comment: Hm. I just put up a no-framework script with no problem. One thing I noticed is that the docs reference `python-3.6.1` instead of `python-3.6.0`. Have you tried switching? Also, to sanity check, can you put the output of `git ls-files` and the `Procfile`?

Comment: @bimsapi I added the ls-files, but I have no Procfile. Is it requiered?

Comment: Yes, pretty sure `Procfile` is required - that's how Heroku knows what script to run for your app. Without it, Heroku doesn't know `automation.py` is anything special. Note though - if `automation.py` doesn't listen on any port, define the process name as `worker` or something. If you define it as `web` Heroku will expect it to bind to an externally visible port (not on localhost). If Heroku doesn't detect a port bind, it reports the app as failed to start.

Comment: Glad that was it. Out of curiosity, is the app just a batch processor, or does it listen for web requests, too?

Comment: @bimsapi The app is a Reddit bot using PRAW. It does react to messages and comments, so I guess it listens to web requests. Another problem was presented, and the Heroku creates two workers for some reason, but I didn't look for the root of the problem yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to `runtime.txt` and `requirements.txt`, a `Procfile` is required - that's how Heroku knows what script to run for your app. Without it, Heroku doesn't know `automation.py` is anything special. Note though - if your script doesn't listen on any port, define the process name as "worker" or anything other than "web". If you define it as "web" Heroku will expect it to bind to an externally visible port (not on localhost). If Heroku doesn't detect a port bind within 60 seconds, it reports the app as failed to start