# Is it possible to deploy UDP listening python-server in Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, udp

I'm trying to deploy [the following python server in Heroku](https://github.com/RabidTunes/HolePuncher/blob/master/Server.py). I've also created a Procfile with the following contents

```
worker: python ./Server.py
```

Heroku says that it has been deployed successfully, but the python server has some lines like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    reactor.listenUDP(port, ServerProtocol())
    print('Listening on *:%d' % (port))
    reactor.run()
```

The print line "Listening on..." does not get printed anywhere, so I guess it is not running? How can I check this? Is it even possible to deploy this server?

Comment: _I stand corrected: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45817486/10761353 (always-on *is* an available option)_ Also, if your code is listening on port 5000, how does Heroku know to forward (port 80/443/etc.) traffic to your code on port 5000?

Comment: But I only need the port specified in the `reactor.listenUDP` line, I dont need to listen on ports 80/443. I took a look at your post, so you mean i would need a Procfile but instead of worker type a "One-off" type?

Comment: A quick review of the docs suggests a ‘web’ type dyno will be always on (and sleeps after 30m of inactivity). What you’ll need to figure out is how to configure Heroku to forward specific ports’ data to your dyno (e.g. on port 5000) running the code above.